# Pass array in query params httr

Tags: r, httr

How do I pass an array into the query of httr?
The request url should look like that:
https://www.example.com/xyz?type=3&type=5

My current code looks like that:

```
POST(url,
query = data.frame("something" = "somethingElse", type = ),
add_headers(.headers = c("token" = token),
encode = "json")
```

How do I add those types from the url example to my R example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default encoding for `httr` doesn't like to use the same name multiple times, but it is possible to separate your values into lists which have duplicate names. Here's a helper function i've used that can help

```
flattenbody <- function(x) {
  # A form/query can only have one value per name, so take
  # any values that contain vectors length >1 and
  # split them up
  # list(x=1:2, y="a") becomes list(x=1, x=2, y="a")
  if (all(lengths(x)<=1)) return(x);
  do.call("c", mapply(function(name, val) {
    if (length(val)==1 || any(c("form_file", "form_data") %in% class(val))) {
      x <- list(val)
      names(x) <- name
      x
    } else {
      x <- as.list(val)
      names(x) <- rep(name, length(val))
      x
    }
  }, names(x), x, USE.NAMES = FALSE, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}
```

Then you could use it with something like

```
POST(url,
  query = flattenbody(list(something="somethingElse", type = c(3, 5))),
  add_headers(.headers = c("token" = token)),
  encode = "json"
)
```

Comment: That does not work if I have to give in aditional query parameters as I defined in my example above. It gets converted into type = 3 & type.1 = 5

Comment: Got it now, by adding all aditional parameters into the list in flattenbody it works, thank you